# Why is heat transfer better from within circular tubes versus ex. square tubes?

Tags: thermodynamics

It is claimed that heat exchange, through the tube-suface, is best from within circular tubes versus either (not sure which is correct):

- from outside of the tube itself
- other shapes like for example a square tube

What is the reasoning behind this claim?
Let's say we are talking about a tube and shell heat exchanger, maybe that narrows it down a bit.

Comment: 'Heat transfer in tubes' could mean a few different things. As could 'best'. Please be more specific. Nevertheless, whenever 'circular' is optimal, it's usually a consequence of it having the minimum circumference for a given area (or minimum surface area for a given cross-sectional area, in the case of a tube).

Comment: Added som more details, it might clarify the question a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The incoming waves will terminate against each other in the corners of the square pipe, meaning there is a deficit of heat in the faces of the square.

If that's true, we should add more corners, and waste less material.

A square has 4 corners, with not a lot of heat on the center of the faces.

An octagon has 8 corners, with $ 1 \over 2 $ of the wastage.

16 corners is $ 1 \over 4 $ of the wastage.

32 is $ 1 \over 8 $

64 is $ 1 \over 16 $

4000 is $ 1 \over 1000 $

So as you can see the limit of 'waste' approaches 0 as the number of corners increases to infinity.

So if you have infinite corners, a circle, you get really close to 0 wasted heat transfer area. Therefore circular tubes are just more efficient.

EDIT: If you're talking about fluid, a circle is still better than any cornered shape for transfer.

For example, a circle of radius r = 0.5 will fit into a square of side s = 1 perfectly.

Although the square has more 'area', the maximum rate of flow of a liquid would be in the center radiating outward and slowing down.

If it radiates outward and decreases speed until contacting the walls, you want a shape that has all walls in contact (circle), otherwise your flow terminates at contact with the walls (square) and the corners are left out, or incredibly inefficient.

So if you are budgeted copper for a pipe of cross-sectional area A, make sure that it is not wasted what-so-ever. So for A = 1 for a square, you have $ 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4 $. For a circle you have $ 2 \pi \sqrt{1 \over \pi} = 3.454 $.

Less material, same area. Cost effective.

Comment: In other words, you seem to be saying that the pipe walls have thermal conductivity normal to the wall, but zero conductivity parallel to the surface. Are you sure about that?

Comment: It's not zero. It's just not as much, since the surface area of a corner approaches zero when you view it in a 2D frame of reference. And since heat will dissipate with the square of the distance from the point of contact, and your waves will 'contact' more in the corners, the middle of the faces (walls) will carry less heat.

Comment: Wait what, I think I misread. Yes, they have normal conduction. Yes, they have parallel conduction. It's the same thing for a flow out of the pipe. What a square pipe does not have, is equidistant normal contact from the center as you approach the edge. Therefore less conductivity in the corners.

Comment: so convection heat propagates in waves?

Comment: Waves, particles, the reasoning is the same here.

Answer (score 1):

the shape and area of the cross section of the pipe can change flow property along the stream. The fluid velocity in a pipe changes from zero at the surface because of the no-slip condition to a maximum at the pipe center.

In fluid flow, it is convenient to work with an average velocity which remains constant in incompressible flow.
Laminar flow in a round pipe prescribes that there are a bunch of circular layers (lamina) of liquid, each having a velocity determined only by their radial distance from the center of the tube. the center is moving fastest while the liquid touching the walls of the tube is stationary (due to the no-slip condition).But infact most of the liquid which has lower/near viscosity of water will flow at turbulant regime.
Temperature of liquid reduces/increases as it moves forward and the bends and joints creates pressure drop as well as turbulent flow which increases heat transfer.

The rectangular cross section will have unstable flow as the formation of eddies near to walls.and the effective hydraulic diameter(For heat transfer) will be lesser for rectangular section.

[image]

Another minor reason is Circular pipes can withstand large pressure differences between the inside and the outside without undergoing any significant distortion, but noncircular pipes cannot.

Comment: But eddies, don't they signify more turbulence, and there is a higher heat transfer when more turbulence.
I guess when you have eddies, you have a lower renewal of "new fluid" (eddies recycle fluid, slowing down overall average total speed => mass/volume flow). And if the fluid isn't recycled the temperature difference becomes as big as it can be, but lower when we have eddies (as the liquid changes temperature with time). Lower temperature difference means lower heat transfer, as heat transfer is directly related to temperature difference, increase one you increase the other.

Comment: Turbulence causes better heat transfer. Considering the fact that more agitation causes faster mixing of molecules and causing average temp difference. But energy to form eddies are from the fluid pressure and due to this, there will be  pressure drop in the line causing fluid velocity to reduce. It is not true that higher the turbulence, Heat transfer is better. At higher turbulence/agitation the liquid starts to increase its temp. we have tested this phenomenon in our lab and the results shows the same.